# Is $A + A^{-1}$ always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. Then is $A + A^{-1}$ invertible for any $A$?

I have a hunch that it's false, but can't really find a way to prove it. If you give a counterexample, could you please explain how you arrived at the counterexample? Thanks.

This isn't HW, and I don't really have any work to show.

Comment: $A+A^{-1}$ is invertible if and only if $I+A^2=A(A^{-1}+A)$ is invertible. So, the whole point is whether $i$ or $-i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 55):

Let $A=[i]{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}$.

Comment: This is a good one!

Comment: Who uses 1 x 1 matrices?

Comment: I do. I don't really like saying a matrix is a regular number. But if you have a problem with this, wait until you see a $0\times 0$ matrix.

Comment: Or worse, a $0 \times 3$ matrix!

Comment: @Hurkyl Indeed $\ddot \smile$.

Comment: Actually, in quadratic forms, it is entirely natural to identify 1 by 1 matrices and numbers. Given a column vector $x$ and a symmetric matrix $A,$ we take $x^T A x$ to be a number.

Comment: Since I think of it, we take $x \cdot y = x^T y.$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, of course, there is a natural correspondence. I myself have treated $1\times 1$ as numbers, butI dislike doing so.

Comment: $n\times 0$-matrices always break my ad hoc matrix libraries, $0\times n$-matrices are ok, though.

Comment: @GitGud: I made an example of such this $1\times 1$ matrix in the class today. it seems that they are useless in Linear Algebra! Nice answer, short but so sweet like a candy. :D +1

Comment: @GitGud, you are a man of refined taste.

Comment: @WillJagy That made me laugh in real life.

Comment: @Hurkyl Just saw this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560736/what-is-a-0-times0-or-0-times3-matrix

Answer (score 14):

As the other answers show, the answer is no. However, if $A$ is symmetric it is true (Hermitian in the complex case): Let $A$ have eigenvalues  $a_i$, and note that $A+A^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $a_i + a_i^{-1}$. These are zero if and only if $a_i^2 = -1$. But this is not possible since $a_i$ is real. Hence $A + A^{-1}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 11):

There is a complex number $i\ne0$ with the property that $i+i^{-1}=0$, or put otherwise $i^2+1=0$. It behaves exactly like 
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},$$
a rotation by $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Diagonal matrix is a good thing to try out first, especially when their inverses are simple.