# What is a $0\times0$ or $0\times3$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the comments to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/560447/196), the following exchange was noted:

> ... wait until you see a 0×0 matrix.

and

> ... or worse, a 0×3 matrix!

What are these things? Do they have a name or any special proprieties? Where are they used?

Comment: I think they were kidding around with each other.

Comment: The determinant of the $0\times0$ matrix is equal to $1$. I don't know about $0\times3$ matrices--maybe APL has such things?

Comment: I sometimes use these matrices in proofs by induction, where the case $n=0$ is sometimes easier than the case $n=1$.  It is simply a matrix with nothing in it.  It looks like this: $[]$.  For example, if I am trying to prove the Choleski factorization theorem for $n\times n$ matrices, the $n=0$ case is trivial, and the argument "if it is true for $n$ then it is true for $n+1$" works just as well for $n=0$ as it does for $n=1$.

Comment: @BettyMock Nope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Matrices" with zero rows/columns can be thought of as linear transformations to/from zero-dimensional vector spaces. A $0\times n$ matrix can also be thought of as an empty array of numbers which maps everything to the zero vector. They have their usefulness in specifying initial/terminal objects in computer programming.

Comment: But a zero-dimensional vector space is not a vector space, right?

Comment: @PeterFranek A zero-dimensional vector space is a vector space, consisting of the set $\{\vec 0\}$ which only has the zero vector, and it is the span of the empty set (which is also a basis). The empty set itself, on the other hand, is not a vector space (since vector spaces are required to have a zero vector).

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest to understand if you view matrices and vectors as functions, i.e., if you see the space of $n$-by-$n$ real matrices $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ as the space of functions
$$
M: \{1,\ldots,m\} \times \{1,\ldots,n\} \longrightarrow \mathbb R
\tag 1
$$
that assign real numbers (resp. numbers from your favourite field) to pairs of numbers $(i,j)$ no bigger than $m$ and $n$. Normally we denote $M(i,j)$ as $M_{ij}$, but that's just notation. (For vectors, just take either $m$ or $n$ to be $1$.)

If $n$ is zero, then the integer interval $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is empty, and therefore so is the Cartesian product, which means that both zero-by-zero, $n$-by-zero and zero-by-$n$ matrices and vectors should all be understood as functions
$$
M:\varnothing \longrightarrow \mathbb R
\tag 2
$$
from the empty set to the field.

And this means, in turn, that this question is simply a version of a much more "vanilla" example of a question that trips people up:

> is there a function from the empty set to the reals?

The answer to this is yes, and it's known as the "empty function", which is explained in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#empty_function) and in nice threads on this site starting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757427/explain-there-is-a-unique-function-from-emptyset-to-any-set-a) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/why-is-an-empty-function-considered-a-function) and in other linked threads.

In short, the empty function into $\mathbb R$ is the function which assigns a real number to every element $i\in\varnothing$ $-$ which is easy, since there are no such $i$s and therefore no need to do any actual assignments of real numbers.

Or, in other words, an $n$-by-zero vector is an array of $n$ rows where each row has one real number for each column, but there are no columns and therefore no numbers. And a zero-by-zero matrix is an array of numbers in columns and rows with one real number at each row-column intersection, but there are no columns and no rows so there are no numbers.

---

That said, things get more interesting when you want to see matrices as more than just arrays of numbers, and you also want to understand them as concrete representations of a linear map between vector spaces.

As a general rule, if you have a mapping $A:V\to W$, where $\dim(V)=n$ and $\dim(W)=m$ and you have bases $\beta = \{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ for $V$ and $\gamma = \{w_1,\cdots,w_m\}$ for $W$, the matrix representation for $A$ is the set of numbers $A_{ij}$ such that
$$
A(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m A_{ij} w_i.
\tag 3
$$

What happens when $n$ (resp. $m$) is zero? In this case, the vector space itself, $V$, has dimension zero, which means that $V=\{\vec 0\}$. That means that $V$ is the vector space that consists only of the zero vector, which is spanned by the empty basis $\beta = \varnothing$.

So, with that in mind:

- If $n=0$, then equation $(3)$ is trivially true for all $v_j\in \beta$, since there are no such $v_j$ to worry about.
- If $m=0$, then the summation $\sum_{i=1}^m$ is empty, which means that it defaults to zero (as all empty summations should). And, of course, this is completely in line with the fact that $m=0$ implies that our linear map is $A: V\longrightarrow W=\{\vec 0\}$ and can only ever produce the zero vector.

And finally, to top it all off: what linear map does the zero-by-zero matrix correspond to? well, to the only possible linear map
$$
A: \{\vec 0\} \longrightarrow \{\vec 0\},
\tag 4
$$
which assigns the zero vector to every basis vector $v_j$ in the basis $\beta$ for $V=\{\vec 0\}$ (of which there aren't any).