# Explain "There is a unique function from $\emptyset$ to any set $A$".

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

My book says:

> There is a unique function from $\emptyset$ to any set $A$.

I don't understand how that is. Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$. Which element of $A$ do we map $\emptyset$ to? Do we map $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$? But $\emptyset\notin A$!

Thanks.

Comment: There is but one way to nothing at all.

Comment: In order to understand the *empty function*, you must remember that a *function* in set theory **is** a set. Thus, the *emptyset* works well also as "emptyfunction" : just as the emptyset does not contain members, in the same way the "emptyfunction" does not map anything anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

You don't map $\emptyset$ to an element of $A$ because $\emptyset$ is not an element of $\emptyset$. To define a map $\emptyset\to A$, we must, for each element of $\emptyset$, specify an element of $A$. This task is easy: Let's get started - done!

Answer (score 5):

The function is called the empty function. The empty function $f:\emptyset \to A$ doesn't map $\emptyset$ to anything, since $\emptyset\notin \emptyset$. There is nothing in $\emptyset$, so $f$ doesn't map anything anywhere.

Why is it unqiue? Well, suppose we have a function $g:\emptyset\to A$. Then trivially $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in \emptyset$ (since there are no such $x$), so $g=f$.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that a function from $X$ to $Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ which has some particular properties.

If $X=\varnothing$, what is $X\times Y$? and how many subsets does it have?